# Replace text generate issue

Tags: android, string, replace

How to replace text without replacing character in between word,

`String test = "This is the test String for replace is best";`

```
txtReplaceText.setText(test.replace("is","    "));
```

[image]

Here is the output i don't want to remove "**This**"

Comment: How many occurences of "is" do you have ? This format of this example is always the same ? Is the word "is" always in the second position ?

Comment: Actually String is not fix and also replace word not fixed

Comment: You could split the string, remove "is" and then join it again. Or, you could search for " is ". But, since your single word "is" could be surrounded by other characters than spaces (dots, exclamation marks, tabs...)... you may want to use a regular expression.

Comment: i try this " is " but not working bcoz string not match

Comment: Did you assign it to a variable? Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), `String.replace` does not seem to replace it inline. It replaces and then returns the transformed String. So `String str = test.replace(" is ", "    "); txtReplaceText.setText(str)`.

Comment: Then what happen when "is" first character in the string, it will not replace, i already try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` :

```
String test = "This is the test String for replace is best";
String regex = "(?<=^| )is(?= |$)";
String output = test.replaceAll(regex, " yourNewString ");
System.out.println(output);
```

- `(?<=^| )` matches the beginning of line or a space
- `(?= |$)` matches the end of line or a space

You can add more characters to the regex in order to fit your needs like `"(?<=^| )is(?= |\\!|\\?|,|.|$)"` to fit the end of a sentence.

It should return:

```
"This yourNewString the test String for replace yourNewString best"
```

Best